# Python: Redundancy when iterating through nested dictionary

Tags: python, excel, dictionary, tree, iteration

I have a nested dictionary which I am trying to loop through in order to write to an excel file.

This is the code which initiates and creates the nested dictionary

```
def tree(): return defaultdict(tree)
KMstruct = tree()
for system in sheet.columns[0]:
if system.value not in KMstruct:
    KMstruct[system.value]
    for row in range(1,sheet.get_highest_row()+1):
        if sheet['A'+str(row)].value == system.value and sheet['B'+str(row)].value not in KMstruct:
            KMstruct[system.value][sheet['B'+str(row)].value]
            if sheet['B'+str(row)].value == sheet['B'+str(row)].value and sheet['C'+str(row)].value not in KMstruct:
                KMstruct[system.value][sheet['B'+str(row)].value][sheet['C'+str(row)].value]
                if sheet['C'+str(row)].value == sheet['C'+str(row)].value and sheet['D'+str(row)].value not in KMstruct:
                    KMstruct[system.value][sheet['B'+str(row)].value][sheet['C'+str(row)].value][sheet['D'+str(row)].value]
                    KMstruct[system.value][sheet['B'+str(row)].value][sheet['C'+str(row)].value][sheet['D'+str(row)].value] = [sheet['E'+str(row)].value]
```

This is the code where I loop through it:

```
for key in KMstruct.keys():
r += 1
worksheet.write(r, col,     key)
for subkey in KMstruct[key]:
    if currsubkeyval != subkey:
        r += 1
        worksheet.write(r, col,     key)
    r +=1
    worksheet.write(r, col, key + '\\' + subkey)
    for item in KMstruct[key][subkey]:
        if curritemval != item:
            r +=1
            worksheet.write(r, col, key + '\\' + subkey)
        for subitem in KMstruct[key][subkey][item]:
            r += 1
            worksheet.write(r, col, key + '\\' + subkey + '\\' + item)
            worksheet.write(r, col + 1, subitem)
            curritemval = item
            for finalitem in KMstruct[key][subkey][item][subitem]:
                r += 1
                worksheet.write(r, col, key + '\\' + subkey + '\\' + item + '\\' + subitem)
                worksheet.write(r, col + 1, KMstruct[key][subkey][item][subitem])
```

Bear with me on this code since I am a noob, I am aware that this is not so beautiful. Anyhow, my problem is the last loop. I am trying to take the string values in `KMstruct[key][subkey][item][subitem]` but the loop variable `lastitem` goes through each char of key's string value (note: the key `subitem` contains a list of strings). This means that if I only have one value that is to be written, it gets written as many times as there are characters in the string.

E.g.: value: apple will be written on a new excel row 5 times

What am I doing wrong here?

Edit: The issue on the redundancy has been solved but now I need to understand if I am doing something wrong when assigning my lastitem, i.e. my list of strings, to the subitem key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that in Python a `str` is also an iterable, for example:

```
>>> for s in 'hello':
...    print(s)

h
e
l
l
o
```

So you either need to avoid iterating when the value is a `str`, or wrap the `str` in another iterable (e.g. a `list`) so that it can be handled the same way.  This is made slightly difficult by how you are structuring your code. For example, the following:

```
for key in KMstruct.keys():
    for subkey in KMstruct[key]:
```

...can be written as:

```
for key, value in KMstruct.items():
    for subkey, subvalue in value.items():
```

...giving you the *value* on each loop, making it possible to apply a test.

```
for key, val in KMstruct.items():
r += 1
worksheet.write(r, col,     key)

for subkey, subval in val.items():
    if currsubkeyval != subkey:
        r += 1
        worksheet.write(r, col,     key)
    r +=1
    worksheet.write(r, col, key + '\\' + subkey)

    for item, itemval in subval.items():
        if curritemval != item:
            r +=1
            worksheet.write(r, col, key + '\\' + subkey)

        for subitem, subitemval in itemval.items():
            r += 1
            worksheet.write(r, col, key + '\\' + subkey + '\\' + item)
            worksheet.write(r, col + 1, subitem)
            curritemval = item

            # I am assuming at this point subitemval is either a list or a str?
            if type(subitemval) == str:
                # If it is, wrap it as a list, so the next block works as expected
                subitemval = [subitemval] 

            for finalitem in subitemval:
                r += 1
                worksheet.write(r, col, key + '\\' + subkey + '\\' + item + '\\' + subitem)
                worksheet.write(r, col + 1, finalitem) # This should be finalitem, correct?
```

Here we test the type of the `subitemval` and if it is a `str` wrap it in a list `[str]` so the following block iterates as expected. There is also an apparent bug where you are not outputting the `finalitem` on the last line. It's not posssible to test this without your example data but it should be functionally equivalent.

Comment: This worked perfectly, thanks a lot! On your question regarding whether subitemval is a list or a str the answer is that subitemval should be a list of str. So what I want to achieve is to write all the subitemval, i.e. finalitem for respective subitem. Do you know how I can approach that maybe?

Comment: The above code should do exactly that! The type-check should ensure `subitemval` is always a list, so `for finalitem in subitemval` will iterate it correctly.

Comment: Unfortunately that is not the case, for the moment it only prints out the first subitemval. I'm suspecting I have done something wrong when building my dictionary and assigning the subitemval. Do you mind looking at that part as well?

Comment: Not at all, add your data structure/creation to the question and I'll take a look.

Comment: @Sajruss will take a look later. In the meantime try experimenting by printing out the values at each level e.g. `print(subitemval)` to see if the values match what you expect.

Comment: Thanks again. I have now experimented a bit and it is as I suspected that the subitemval list only contains one value and doesn't become populated. So something must be wrong when I assign the values to the keys.

Comment: You don't have to look into it, I solved the issue now myself. Thanks for all the help anyhow! @mfitzp

Answer (score 0):

Your immediate problem is that the last line of your example should be:

```
                worksheet.write(r,col+1, finalitem)
```

BTW, your code would be a lot easier to read if you created occasional temporary variables like:

```
        subitemlist = KMstruct[key][subkey][item]
        for subitem in subitemlist:
```